# How to show a full post, not just an excerpt

Tags: posts, excerpt, blog

I have a blog page where blog posts have an excerpt on with a continue reading link below.

When the link is clicked the full post should appear/or should be diverted to.

This isn't that case. The user is diverted to the post, however only the excerpt is displayed along with a continue reading link which doesn't activate anything.

I have deactivated all plugins, I have also played around with the settings but can't find any triggers.

Blog Page - http://vikingsandc.co.uk/strength-and-conditioning-blog/
Post Page - http://vikingsandc.co.uk/2012/11/test-text-test-text/

Comment: does that also happen with an unedited version of your theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) instead of [`the_excerpt`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) when you display your 'single' post.

If you would post your code, you might get a more detailed answer.

Comment: Which .PHP file (line estimate would help) can I find the part of the code you need in?

Comment: That depends on the theme. (If your theme where using [`body_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) I could tell by looking.) If you have a `single.php`, chances are that that is it. Otherwise, you probably need to write a switch into `index.php`, but it possible that those files are using [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) or some other means to include the formatting source from still other files.

Comment: found it... sorry I hadn't realised you told me the location (single post) found the criminal and changed it over as suggested. Thank you for the quick response

Answer (score -2):

in `content.php` file find the line with `the_excerpt();` and replace it with `the_content();`